# Get MIME Type via PHP

Tags: php, zend-framework, codeigniter, mime-types, mime

I have local access to files, which I need to get their MIME types. Working in WAMP/LAMP, CodeIgniter, and Zend libraries. What's the best way to get MIME type information?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no easy way. You could try:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php

```
// return mime type ala mimetype extension
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
```

Of course, this assumes you can install PECL extensions.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need head. Quickest way is to do a head request, or in PHP under apache you can use [apache_lookup_uri](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.apache-lookup-uri.php) or in PHP 5.3 you can use FileInfo (I'd still recommend apache_lookup_uri or a simple head request though).

Comment: `apache_lookup_uri` does not give you a MIME type, AFAIK. FileInfo will work, if you have PECL, as noted by @David.

Comment: apache_lookup_uri amongst other things returns 'content_type' which is the mime-type

Comment: I renamed one of my .PHP files to .PNG and `apache_lookup_uri()` returned `image/png` as the Content-Type, which is proof that this is nothing more than an extension to "fake" mime type mapping. Furthermore, it might be dangerous since Apache actually requests the file and might lead to code execution (not sure about this).

Comment: @Alix-Axel seems obvious enough, since apache doesn't have any sniffing in it and relies on mapping file extensions to media types.

Answer (score 1):

Its never a good idea to try and find the mime type based on the file extension, as this can obviously be renamed by the used whos uploading - from .exe to .jpg

Real mime type detection is part of your overall security measures.

Answer (score 0):

Parse your Apache's `mime.types` file.

Answer (score 0):

Try CI's built in function "get_mime_by_extension($file)".  You can find it in the "system/helpers/file_helper.php" file